# Implementing pagination in MVC - Servlets + JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, pagination

[MVC, Servlets + JSP, JPA, MySQL]
I am working on simple Blog application. I am using JPA to map entities to MySQL tables. Here is code excerpt from entities in question:

Entity `Post`:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getNewestPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.date DESC"), // getting resultList ordered by date
    @NamedQuery(name = "getMostVisitedPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.visitors DESC") // ordered by most visited
})
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "post")
    public class Post implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer id; 

        @Column(name = "post_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "post_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
        private Date date;

        @Column(name = "post_summary", length=1000, unique = false, nullable = true)
        private String summary;

        @Column(name = "post_content", length=50000, unique = false, nullable = false)
        private String content;

        @Column(name = "post_visitors", unique = false, nullable = false)
        private Integer visitors;

        @OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "post")
        private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    ...
```

Entity `Comment`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "comment_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "comment_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "comment_content", length=600, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "post_id", referencedColumnName="post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post; ...
```

Blog home page should contain summaries of 10 newest posts. So, in `PostDAO` object I have defined next method (returns all posts from db ordered by date):

```
public List<Post> getNewestPosts(){

    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getNewestPosts");
    List<Post> resultList = (List<Post>) q.getResultList();

    if (resultList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
        return resultList;
}
```

I would like to implement pagination in some simple way, probably passing certain request parameters and reading data in `jsp` using `jstl` (i'm not yet familiar with `jquery`). Now, how to approach to implementing pagination in `MVC`? Which parameters I need to be attaching to request? How should I approach to implementing page navigation links (`previous, page numbers, next`) in `JSP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the setMaxResults and the setFirstResult methods on the namedQuery. Keep passing the First result as a function of the number of records to be displayed on the page and the page number.

If you use Spring MVC there is already a way to do it and you can take a look at the PageListHolder api documentation. I havent used this but i have stumbled upon the API.

Comment: thanks, added `setFirstResult(pageNumber)` and `setMaxResults(postsPerPage)` to method `getNewestPosts(int pageNumber, postsPerPage)` (added attributes to method)